# Every other element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to access every other/second element in an array, such as 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.. but can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

This is my function:

```
 function tall(nummer) {
var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
 if (nummer == 5) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= tall.length; i++) {
        if(!i % 2 == 0) {
            const partall = a => a.filter(e => +e == e && e%2);
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = partall(tall);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you getting any errors? `for(var i = 0; i <= tall.length; i++)` should lead to a nullpointerexception as the index ends 1 before the length

Comment: @elPolloLoco nope

Comment: wait, where are you accessing tall anyways?

Comment: its a div in html, if thats what you are asking

Comment: Why is there a loop of the array and inside the loop filtering the array?
On every iteration, you just remove what you stick in the innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an order of operations issue with the line

```
if(!i % 2 == 0) {
```

Where the `!` has higher precedence than the `%`. So the value of i is being coerced to a boolean (false for any non-zero number) and then that boolean is coerced to a `0` for the modulus operation (the result of `0 % 2` always being 0 so the statement always evaluates to true). If you wanted to check if `i` was even, you would want to write that

```
if(i % 2 == 0)// i divided by two has no remainder
```

however, you are doing this in a loop, and in the truthy case you are applying a filter to the entire array. The result of that filter operation won't change per iteration of the loop, so there's really no point to doing it more than once.

```
const partall = a => a.filter(e => +e == e && e%2);
```

`+e` is a unary operator to coerce the value in `e` to a number (which it already is) but then you loosely compare a number to `e && e%2` which will result in a boolean (true if the number is not evenly divisible by two). If you want all even numbers, you can rewrite this

```
const partall = a => a.filter(e => !(e%2));
```

The following should work. I've removed the loop entirely as it serves no real function here.

```js
 function tall(nummer) {
var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
 if (nummer == 5) {
    
      const partall = a => a.filter(e => !(e%2));
      document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = partall(tall);
  }
}
tall(5);
```

```html
<div id='tall'></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND) `&`  to discern even-odd indices and filter.

```
tall.filter((_,i) => i&1)
```

```js
var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
result = tall.filter((_,i) => i&1);

console.log( result );
```

Comment: Clever, really nice